# java script call methods from another methods

Tags: javascript

I'm new in js.

I see code example:

```
foo.bar().baz()
```

How described foo bar and baz that we can call so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What are you are probably after is called chaining.  A method can return the object it's running on `this`, so that another method may be called.

```
var foo = {
  bar: function() {
    doStuff();
    return this;
  },

  baz: function() {
    doOtherStuff();
    return this;
  }
};

foo.bar().baz();
```

This is exactly how jQuery works, in order to allow things like:

```
$('#foo')
  .html('<p>hi</p>')
  .addClass('selected')
  .css('font-size', '24px')
  .show();
```

Comment: a quick comment for clarification since you said that you are new to JS, this is not a JS feature, you can achieve this in different programming languages by returning an object which has other methods you can invoke

Comment: Yep.  In fact, wikipedia has example in C#, C++, Java and PHP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you had an object foo with two methods: bar and bad.  The implementation of bar would be like this: function bar() { /* do work */ return this; } That returns foo itself so you can call baz since it's defined in foo.